# Tocloft check if custom list is empty

Tags: tocloft

I have defined a custom list called "List of Missing Things" using the package `tocloft`. The list contains a couple of items, and the `listof` command does give me the respective list. Essentially, this list should only show up if it does contain items. Otherwise, I would like it to not print anything at all. I'd like to use this to mark stuff I still need to add in my thesis, but then not remove anything else from the code once every missing thing has been resolved one way or another.

What I would like is to use as little additional packages as possible, for compatibilities' sake. I have already put this into `.sty` form, and I am still considering uploading it at some point if it turns out to be useful.

So what I **thought** I needed to do was check the counter created by the `listof` command. I tried to use `\ifnum\value{missingthings}=0`, but since I use the command right at after `\listoftables`, the value of the counter `missingthings` is 0.0. I figured I would need to check if the file `test.lomt` does contain any lines of content.

How would I go about doing this? I have read similar topics on here using the package `etoc` or similar things checking the .toc file, but that doesn't really help me in my case, does it?

Also, what's wrong with my `ifnum`? It does not appear to work properly as the `\listofmissingthings` is still being printed even if placed at the beginning of the document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlistof[section]{missingthings}{lomt}{List of Missing Things}

\newcommand{\missingthing}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{missingthings}
\par\noindent\textbf{Missing Thing \themissingthings: #1.} \newline #2
\addcontentsline{lomt}{missingthings}{\protect\numberline{\themissingthings}#1}\par}

\let\oldlistofmissingthings\listofmissingthings%
\renewcommand{\listofmissingthings}{ % Makes LoMT show up in ToC
    \ifnum\value{missingthings}=0%
    \oldlistofmissingthings%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Missing Things}%
    \else%
    %
    \fi%
}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofmissingthings

The current value of the counter missingthings is \themissingthings.
\section{Example}
\missingthing{First Text goes here}{This text only appears in my document, but not in my List of Missing Things}
\section{Another Example}
The current value of the counter missingthings is \themissingthings.
\end{document}
```

P.S.: I know the use of `tocloft` is not recommended together with KOMA-script classes. I have not found the courage to change my document class, so this is a topic for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of two new counters and auxiliary (`*.aux`) file, you could achieve a counter check in the `\listofmissingthings` command to decided if this command will make a output or do nothing. You need run twice in order to have correct outputs.

Two new counters defined as:

```
\newcounter{writecn}
\newcounter{existcn}
```

Initially, they are all equal to 0.

Then, in the definition of `\missingthing` command, add:

```
\ifnum\value{writecn}=0\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{existcn}{1}}\fi%
\ifnum\value{writecn}=1\else\setcounter{writecn}{1}\fi%
```

The first line will immediately write a line in aux file `\setcounter{existcn}{1}`. This will ensure that even the command `\listofmissingthings` are executed before the command `\missingthing`, the counter `existcn` are equal to 1 not 0. The second line just to set the counter `writecn` equal to 1 when it is not equal to 1. In this way, the first line will executed only once even multiple `\missingthing` commands have been issued.

And then in the renewcommand definition of `\listofmissingthings`, use the counter `existcn` to judge if the list and `addtocontentsline` should be include in the output. Like:

```
\renewcommand{\listofmissingthings}{ % Makes LoMT show up in ToC
    \ifnum\value{existcn}=1
    \oldlistofmissingthings%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Missing Things}
    \else\fi%%
}%
```

The full working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcounter{writecn}
\newcounter{existcn}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof[section]{missingthings}{lomt}{List of Missing Things}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\missingthing}[2]{%
\ifnum\value{writecn}=0\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{existcn}{1}}\fi%
\ifnum\value{writecn}=1\else\setcounter{writecn}{1}\fi%
\refstepcounter{missingthings}%
\par\noindent\textbf{Missing Thing \themissingthings: #1.} \newline #2
\addcontentsline{lomt}{missingthings}{\protect\numberline{\themissingthings}#1}\par}
\makeatother

\let\oldlistofmissingthings\listofmissingthings%
\renewcommand{\listofmissingthings}{ % Makes LoMT show up in ToC
    \ifnum\value{existcn}=1
    \oldlistofmissingthings%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Missing Things}
    \else\fi%%
}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofmissingthings
The current value of the counter missingthings is \themissingthings.
\section{Example}
\missingthing{First Text goes here}{This text only appears in my document, but not in my List of Missing Things}
\section{Another Example}
\missingthing{First Text goes here}{This text only appears in my document, but not in my List of Missing Things}
The current value of the counter missingthings is \themissingthings.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for my understanding, the aux file stores the value of the counter writecn. The aux-file will not be deleted every run, otherwise storing information in it wouldn't make sense. So in order for the counter writecn to change back to 0 I would need to delete the aux files (manually)? Edit: Nevermind, it does work without deleting the aux file. Why though? What am I missing?

Comment: @bebarty The aux file be regenerated each time you run to capture the changes you made in the document.